# I just wiped out some Firefox preferences, how do I get them back?

Tags: firefox, cookie

I have cookies set to "only when I say so" in Firefox, and I just accidentally hit "remove all sites" from my list of exceptions. I haven't closed the window yet -- is there a way to get my exceptions list back or is it already wiped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can recover them, but whatever information you may have is under your home in a hidden folder so if you want to  make a backup:

```
cp -rvf $HOME/.mozilla $HOME/mozilla_backup
```

Then, you may have a look at that folder and see if there's something you can recover.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to just copy my entire profile and then compare it.